# batch Get value of variable stored inside variable

Tags: batch-file

I have the name of a variable stored inside another variable and i would to find the value of variable the first variable.

I wrote this code to solve it.

```
set var1=aaa
set var2=bbb
set var3=ccc
set var4=ddd
echo pick number 1 to 4
set /p ReturnCode=
set answer=%%var_%ReturnCode%%%
echo %answer%
```

My trouble is it gives name of variable back instead of value.

For example, if i enter 3 to chose instead of outputting 'ccc', it outputs 'var_3'. I would appreciate any help you could give, Thanks.

Comment: note your variables are var1 var2 var3 but you're trying to use var_*n*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways to do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var1=aaa
set var2=bbb
set var3=ccc
set var4=ddd
echo pick number 1 to 4
set /p ReturnCode=

:: using delayed variable expansion
set answer=!var%ReturnCode%!
echo %answer%

:: using the call double percent trick
call echo %%var%ReturnCode%%%

:: or
call set answer2=%%var%ReturnCode%%%
echo %answer2%
```